# Удаленный срвер не принимает пароль, скрипт ruby 'net/ssh'

Tags: сеть, ruby, ssh

Подключаюсь с помощью ruby к удаленке, передаю команду, но похоже что channel.send_data("passw\n") как то не так отрабатывает, не могу выловить в чем причина.
Не проходит пароль.

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'net/ssh'
...

Net::SSH.start(@hostname, @username, :password => @password) do |session|
stdout = ""
session.exec!(@cmd) do |channel, stream, data|  
    if data =~ /Password/ 
        channel.send_data("passw\n")
    end
    stdout << data
   end   
puts stdout
session.close 
end
```

Comment: а что приходит?

Comment: @Сергей Коновалов  fatal: could not read Password for '... ': No such device or address